# Grid row height distribute evenly to match the grid height in ExtJS4

Tags: css, extjs, grid, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have an ExtJS 4 web app and I have a grid with a set height. The problem I have right now is that the grid has to be a certain height, and the rows often aren't many enough (usually around 31 records) to occupy the entire height of the grid so there is space left below the grid:

[image: Grid Screenshot]

What I want to do is to adjust the row height or something in the grid in such a way that the rows will equally distribute the available grid height amongst themselves.

Is there an easy way to do this? I have styled my grid but it's just for borders and for removing the padding in the row items.

Comment: perhaps try using css .x-grid-row class and adjusting its line-height property dynamically depending or exact number of records you have

Answer (score 1):

You can modify it using css setting **x-grid-table** **height** property to **100%**
like this

```
.my-table .x-grid-table { height: 100%; }
```

You can find a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/overlordhammer/33a4nm13/2/). Hope it helps to solve your problem.